# How to do automatic-sign-in for users who register and get transferred to their account subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, subdomain

I'm building a multi-tenant app where accounts are scoped under subdomains. Assuming *acme.com* is my app and *Elmer* is my user, when Elmer registers at acme.com he is transferred to elmer.acme.com. I want to sign Elmer in after he registers, but I'm having a hard time. I'm using cookies. Here's my sign in method:

```
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    current_user = user
  end
```

Here's part of my Users#create method where users get signed in.

```
if @user.save
  sign_in(@user)
  redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @user.subdomain)
end
```

The cookie is getting set when Elmer is still at *acme.com.* When Elmer is redirected to *elmer.acme.com* the cookie is not valid.

I can set `domain: :all` in my `session_store`, but this breaks a requirement. It would mean Elmer will be signed into `elmer.acme.com`, `buggs.acme.com`, and essentially `*.acme.com`. Elmer's session cookie should only be valid for *elmer.acme.com* and/or *acme.com*.

Any idea how to achieve this? I'm running Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to create/allow a token login for your user, then you could:

1. Have a token on the user model
2. Login with that token (either redirect to a specific URL, or add to your authentication system to login when :token is present)

Sample redirect code:

```
if @user.save
  sign_in(@user)
  redirect_to root_url(user_id: @user.id, subdomain: @user.subdomain, token: @user.token)
end
```

Comment: Isn't that what I have now? The `remember_me` value is essentially that, a token that gets generated when the model is saved. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean redirect to a specific URL that does the login?

Comment: No, you don't have that now. You would need to either enable token_authenticable if Devise, or write a method check to actually sign_in on the redirect based on the token.

Comment: PS: I wrote my own authentication method (a la Rails Tutorial, Michael Hartl)

Comment: I'm going to test this today and mark this answer. I think I understand the gist of what you mean.

Comment: thank you for the idea. I implemented it today and it works perfectly well!